# Update query update zero to database always

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, transactions

I am trying to update the customer table's `due_amount` field if the `mode_of_payment` is `credit`. The query works fine when I paste it directly in the database. But when it comes through the transactions, the value is updated as zero.

I have tried both, writing a normal query and pass to the transaction and generating common functions to create the query. The query produced in both ways works fine when directly pasted into the database. But when try to run it through code value updates as zero

This is the query created and passed to transactionList.

```
 TransactionQueryList.Add("UPDATE `customer_info` SET `due_amount` =  
`due_amount`+'"+ Math.Round(NewBalance,2)+"'WHERE `customer_id` = '"+ CustomerID+"'");
```

This is the query above one produces

```
UPDATE `customer_info` SET `due_amount` = `due_amount`+'241.2' WHERE 
`customer_id` = 'UAUYMMKTQC'
```

This query works when pasted to the database. but not working when I pass through transactions

Here's my transaction code:

```
try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Queries.Count; i++)
            {
                Command.CommandText = Queries[i];

                //MessageBox.Show(Queries[i]);
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                Transaction.Rollback();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            Instance.CloseConnection();
        }
```

### Expected Result

If `mode_of_payment` is credit, then `due_amount` should add to the current amount and store the sum to the database.

### Actual Result

`due_amount` is updated as zero here.

Comment: As a side note: You should start to use parameterized queries immediately.

Comment: And stop putting numbers in `'strings'`

Comment: You show that you add to `TransactionQueryList` but in the code you claim executing the queries there's an iteration over `Queries` not  `TransactionQueryList`.

Comment: @CaiusJard Removed quotes for number and still not working.                  
    UPDATE `customer_info` SET `due_amount` = `due_amount`+723.6 WHERE 
    `customer_id` = '4'

Comment: @fahad please put this code immediately before the loop and post a screenshot of the resulting messagebox: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", Queries));`

Comment: @CaiusJard still it updates zero

Comment: @fahad lol, i love how you removed the quotes from the `723.6` but not the `'4'`

Comment: @fahad I asked for a screenshot of the messagebox because I want to see a string rendering of the entire list of queries you're running

Comment: @stickybit `TransactionQueryList` is just a list. I add all queries to this and at last commit one by one.

Comment: Try to only run the query in question, not the others from the list. And do you have triggers in your database?

Comment: no i don't gave triggers in database

Comment: Is there an Exception? The code you have won't make it obvious, and it doesn't even look like all code paths return a value. Put a breakpoint in the catch block and assign the Exception to a variable so you can see it's details.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried putting a breakpoint in the catch block. But it didn't enter to catch block. and there are no exceptions. the same query works if directly pasted in the database.

Comment: OK, but there is a lot more going on with the code than the sql statement so that doesn't mean there could not possibly be an exception. My next advice would be to trace the database activity and see exactly what commands are being sent. For MSSQL Server you would use SqlProfiler but I don't know what database system you are using.

Comment: I use MySQL for database